# Reference Error JS not defined for Datamap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs, topojson, qliksense

I have a couple of persistent errors in converting this html to the below js:

### html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js?v=1"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      max-width:100%;
      max-height:100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map = new Datamap({
        scope: 'world',
        element: document.getElementById('map')
      })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### js

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',
    'http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.js', 
    'http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js',
    'http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js?v=1',
    'text!./map.css'
],

    function($, D3, Datamap, cssContent) {  
       'use strict';  
        $("<style>").html(cssContent).appendTo("head"); 
        $("<meta>").html("utf-8").appendTo("head"); 

        return {            
            paint: function ( $element, D3, Datamap, layout) {
                try{    
                    $element.empty();
                    var $map = document.createElement("div", {
                        "id": "map"
                    });
                    $element.append( $map );
                    var map = new Datamap({
                        scope: 'world',
                        element: document.getElementById('map')
                    })
                }catch(err){
                    alert(err.message);
                }               
            }
        };
    } );
```

---

### js errors

HTML (first snippet) works perfectly fine, **but js gives me a variation of the following errors:**

1. **ReferenceError: d3 is not defined** (or any of the other js files)
2. **Datamap is not defined**
3. **Datamap is not a constructor**
4. **Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress**

---

### What I've tried thus far

1. Loading the js in paint function via require.toUrl and
   jQuery.getScript, appending the js to head, $.getScript the full url
   outside the main function
2. Combining all the js into one, and also
   embedding them in the main js
3. Sync and async methods of ajax js
   loading
4. Adding the js objects to function($) {  : function($, D3,
   Projection, TopoJson, Datamaps, cssContent) {
5. Referencing the JS files locally, i.e. define( [
   'jquery','./d3.v3.min','./d3.geo.projection.v0', etc...

Context: [For custom Qlik Sense extension](https://community.qlik.com/message/1220734#1220734) which uses [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now (I'm sure it can still be improved, but it's what works for now):

```
require.config({
paths: {
    d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',
    geo: 'http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.js',
    topojson: 'http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js',
    datamaps: 'http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js?v=1'     
},
shim: {
    'd3':{
        exports: "d3"  
    },
    'geo':{
        deps: ["d3"]
    },
    'topojson':{
        deps: ["d3"],
        exports: "topojson"  
    },
    'datamaps':{
        deps: ["d3","topojson"],
        exports: "datamaps"  
    }
  }
}); 
d3 = require('d3');
define( [
  'jquery',
  'd3',
  'geo',
  'topojson',
  'datamaps',
  'text!./map.css'
],
    function($, d3, geo, topojson, Datamap, cssContent) {  
       'use strict';  
        $("<style>").html(cssContent).appendTo("head"); 

        return {            
            paint: function ( $element,layout) {
                try{    
                    $element.empty();
                    $('<div id="map">').appendTo($element);
                    var map = new Datamap({
                        scope: 'world',
                        element: document.getElementById('map')
                    })
                }catch(err){
                    alert(err.message);
                }               
            }
        };
    } );
```